# bash: cannot set terminal process group (951): Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins, chroot

I am trying to execute the following commands from the Jenkins "Execute Shell" area.  While running I am getting the following error. Can anyone help me with this?

```
+ sudo chroot edit
bash: cannot set terminal process group (951): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

[image]

Comment: Bash is told to act as an interactive shell, but isn't given a tty.
Can you add a copy of the code for that build step?

Comment: Also, it's easier to quote that output when you copy/paste the text instead of a screenshot.

Comment: This might be related to a possible bug in su, where this fails with the same error: su -c bash. I found this: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=663200 and this: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=659832 ... that's 2012 and it's 2015 no, so not fixed in 3 years still...?

Comment: Su man page a -c says: "The executed command will have no controlling terminal. This option cannot be used to execute interractive programs which need a controlling TTY.".